# Characters on UISearchbar and the cursor position

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

In am trying to implement that if the user enters the first character of text as *, then the system should automatically add the ending * character and the cursor should be placed in between both * * for the user to type in between the special characters.

I tried the following code, but the cursor is always placed after the end * character.

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text hasPrefix:@"*"])
    {
        [text stringByAppendingString:@"*"];
        self.searchBar.text = text;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Is it possible to handle the place of the cursor on UISearchBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing here is take the current text, append a `"` (not a *), do nothing with the result, and set the search bar's text to what the text was before. How does this work?

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text hasPrefix:@"\""])
    {
        searchBar.text = [text stringByAppendingString:@"\""];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: okay I edited it. I was just playing around with different characters.